# How to handle redirect to Angular from authenticationSuccessHandler in Spring Security

Tags: angular, spring, spring-security, angular-routing

I'm trying to implement **remember me** functionality. The problem is that Angular handle routing in his own way, so from Spring app I can't redirect to a specific path to Angular App. I solve this by sending response with a message where to redirect, then Angular app pars the message and redirect to, a specific path. It works great, but when configuring security it works in slightly different way.

For example when I'm trying to login, I override the successHandler because by default Spring wants to redirect to some url and it can't be handled by Angular.

```java
.and()
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
        .successHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
            AuthenticatedUser user = new AuthenticatedUser(
                    authentication.getName(),
                    authentication.isAuthenticated()
            );
            log.info("Authenticated {}", user);
            response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE);
            response.getWriter().print(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(user));
        })
        .failureHandler((request, response, exception) -> {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "Wrong username and/or password");
        })
```

This works fine, but when it comes to **rememberMe** and **authenticationSuccessHandler** it works in different way. Code looks the same like for login successHandler.

```java
.and()
    .rememberMe()
        .authenticationSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
        AuthenticatedUser user = new AuthenticatedUser(
                    authentication.getName(),
                    authentication.isAuthenticated()
            );
            log.info("Authenticated {}", user);
            response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE);
            response.getWriter().print(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(user));
            redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "");
        }).key("test")
```

But when I do this in this way and siply close tab with the App and open it again Spring serve me a json response with my AuthenticatedUser.

[image: Response by Spring]

I also tried using **RedirectStrategy** in authenticationSuccessHandler to redirect to index.html, root but it didn't work either.

```java
redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "index.html");
redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/");
redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "");
```

I see in the Spring app logs that my rememberMe works fine, but **I don't know how to properly redirect**, that user don't need to login again.